# Database.DMLOptions.DuplicateRuleHeader.allowSave skips all validation rules?

Tags: apex, validation-rule, bug, duplicate-management

Had a project where the client wanted to allow the data to bypass contact duplicate rules they had in place. So figured inserting the new contacts with `Database.DMLOptions.DuplicateRuleHeader.allowSave` would do the trick. 
It will indeed let you save over duplicate rules in place; however, if the record fails a validation rule it will **fail silently**

Example: There is a validation rule on Account, that throws an error when 'Fail_Me__c' = true.

```
Database.DMLOptions dmlOptions = new Database.DMLOptions();
dmlOptions.DuplicateRuleHeader.allowSave = true;
List<SObject> toInsert = new List<SObject>();

Account iPass = new Account();
iPass.Name = 'I Pass validation';
iPass.Fail_Me__c = false;
toInsert.add(iPass);

Account iFail = new Account();
iFail.Name = 'I Fail validation';
iFail.Fail_Me__c = true; // should get an error
toInsert.add(iFail);

Database.insert(toInsert, dmlOptions);

/*shouldn't get here but we do*/
System.debug('*** iPass.Id: ' + iPass.Id);
System.debug('*** iFail.Id: ' + iFail.Id);
```

Completes successfully, no errors, with a result of:

`USER_DEBUG|[15]|ERROR|*** iPass.Id: 00136000002X7U5AAK
USER_DEBUG|[17]|ERROR|*** iFail.Id: null`

Maybe I'm not using it correctly, but something seems off here right?

Comment: Did you try `Database.SaveResult[] srList = Database.insert(toInsert, dmlOptions);` ? and then check the isSuccess() method for each list member in `srList` ?

Answer (score 0):

What if you specify dmlOptions.optAllOrNone = true? By default, that option is false. And you then have to check the Database.SaveResult object to determine which, if any of your records has errors.